# Openlayer2: clustering with stylemap

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using OpenLayers 2.13.1. I could get my clustering work for the vector layer but when I try adding a styleMap to the vector layer, neither the clusters nor the individual points are visible on the map. Below is my code.

function PlotExposuresOnMap(selectedExposures)
     {
         if (exposureLayer)
             map.removeLayer(exposureLayer);

```
     var context = {
         symbol: function (feature) {
             if (feature.cluster) {
                 return '../icons/cluster.png';
             }
             else {
                 return '../icons/marker.png';
             }
         }
     }

     var template = {
         externalGraphic: "${symbol}"
     }
     var style = new OpenLayers.Style(template, { context: context });


     var clusterStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({ distance: 20 });

     var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
         'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
         'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
     });
     exposureLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Exposures", { strategies: [clusterStrategy] /*, styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style)*/});

     map.addLayer(exposureLayer);

     exposureLayer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(selectedExposures));

 }
```

I wanted to display different icons for the markers based on whether it is a clsuter or an individual marker. I am really not sure what is missing.